# Error while compiling java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a reason why when I try to compile the code with eclipse, it gives me an error with id=20 and when I compile it in DOS it works fine?

I used the command line: javac -d . 'filename' for both.

Here's the code:

```
public class MammalInt implements Animal {
    
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Mammal eats.");
    }
    
    public void travel() {
        System.out.println("Mammal travels");
    }
    
    public int noOfLegs() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MammalInt m = new MammalInt();
        m.eat();
        m.travel();
    }
}
```

and Animal.java:

```
package animals;

interface Animal {
    public void eat();
    public void travel();
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, check if you run the right compilation package in eclipse

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to eclipse. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Run -> Run Configurations ... -> Select "Java Appliction" and click "New".

Comment: Never mind, it just doesn't let me run it from the default package. Had to create a separate animals package for it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the full error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at MammalInt.main(MammalInt.java:17)

Comment: ```main() is throwing Error  (id=20) 
 backtrace Object[6]  (id=23) 
 cause Error  (id=20) 
 depth 1 
 detailMessage "Unresolved compilation problem: \n" (id=25) 
 stackTrace StackTraceElement[0]  (id=31) 
 suppressedExceptions Collections$EmptyList<E>  (id=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same problem when I tried to run my program in Eclipse.
It is nothing but you have to write "package" in your file. Check whether you've written package otherwise write package details and it will run smoothly.

Comment: People usually omit the package and import statement when sharing their code.